# Why does recursive function return the value of the first call?

Tags: python, recursion

I got the following helper function, which traverses through a binary tree and saves the height and position additionally. The main idea of the function is to check if two trees are exactly the same, but I am already stuck at the helper function. See input and output below for the exact issue

```
def isSameTree(p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
    
    def helper(node, height, position):
        
        if not node:
            return None
        
        if node.left:
            helper(node.left, height + 1, "left")
        if node.right:
            helper(node.right, height + 1, "right")

        return (node.val, height, position)
        

    return helper(p, 0, "")
```

Example Input:

```
root = TreeNode(1)
root.left = TreeNode(2)
root.right = TreeNode(3)
root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
root.left.right = TreeNode(5)
print(Solution.isSameTree(root, root2))
```

root2 is defined, but plays no major rule for this example. The Output of the print I expected is the very last node without any children, that is `root.left.left = TreeNode(4)`. However, the print statement returns the root node and I cannot understand why. Should not the last recursion call, i.e. the one with no children, return first?

Bonus question: How can I fix the code in such way that I every node, with its height and position gets returned?

Comment: You recurse, but those recursions don't do anything other than return some value that is ignored. I'm skeptical of the entire code, because the return value is "bool" but you're returning a triple of (node, height, position).

Answer (score 0):

You must use the returned value of the helper function when you recurse...

Here the underlying rationale is that 2 trees are equal if their (current) root node either are both null or have same value and both left and right subtrees are equal.

The function using a recursive helper should just translate that in Python language:

```
def isSameTree(p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:

    def helper(node1, node2):
        if node1 is None and node2 is None:   // Ok if both nodes are None
            return True
        if node1 is None or node2 is None:    // not ok if one is None (both was tested above)
            return False
        if node1.value != node2.value:     // if nodes exist they must have same value
            return False
        if not helper(node1.left, node2.left): // left subtree must be equal
            return False
        return helper(node1.right, node2.right) // same for right one

    return helper(p, q)
```

Comment: Why could you not leave out the third if statement and just call helper on the left nodes?

Comment: Because after the first test (which should be followed by an or) this code is just a splitted way to do an *and* on all others conditions... So when reaching the last one, the return is just a shortcut for `if not helper(...):` `return False` `return True`